# How do I find the best location for an AOE ability

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in unity3d. I have an AI agent that has a "
"targetFinder" method to decide who it will attack. For basic "nearest enemy", it's pretty straightforward:

```
/* TargetFinder
   Finds the closest enemy */
Transform TargetFinder(Transform source) {
  GameObject[] EnemiesInScene = GetEnemies();
  enemies = enemies.OrderBy(
        (GameObject g) => Vector3.Distance(g.transform.position, source)
    ).ToArray();
  return enemies.Length == 0 ? null : enemies[0].transform;
}
```

However, let's say I want to give the AI a "fireball" AOE attack, which does damage in a radius and travels from the enemy to a fixed point in the scene. I'd want some sort of method like:

```
/* TargetFinder
   Finds the transform T within RANGE of SOURCE that maximizes 
   The number of enemy units within RADIUS of T */
Transform TargetFinder(Transform source, float range, float radius) {
  GameObject[] EnemiesInScene = GetEnemies();

  // ???
  return T;
}
```

Given the enemies, what's the best way to find T? I was imagining a few ideas, but they all seemed very brute-force (e.g. instantiating a bunch of colliders, or doing some sort of topography and picking the highest point)

Would love any insight on if there's any algorithmic or unity-based approach to solving this targeting problem

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for some variation of [kmeans-clustering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) see also e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55854/finding-a-known-number-of-circle-centers-that-maximize-the-number-of-points-with)

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767247/how-to-select-the-most-amount-of-scattered-points-contained-in-a-radius) could be a duplicate of your question as well

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for helping to find those. 

I thought of the k-means, but I think that it'd be prohibitively expensive if n gets high. Seems like this is just a hard problem based on the second one!